# Migration to IIS8 on Windows 2012 Server - Remote Post now shows a blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have recently moved a V2.20 nopCommerce website that was running on IIS6 on Windows 2003 server to IIS8 running on Windows 2012 server and now when the remote post is performed for the WorldPay module, all I see is a blank, white screen?

I have a feeling that this isn't limited to the WorldPay module or indeed nopCommerce and is more of an MVC issue with code that was developed in an earlier version of ASP.Net running on ASP.Net 4.5.

So does anyone have any ideas or resolutions as to why a remote post will not work, see example code below of the remote post, the form when it is written to the HTTP context just doesn't seem to fire the body onload event.

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;

namespace Nop.Web.Framework
{
/// <summary>
/// Represents a RemotePost helper class
/// </summary>
public partial class RemotePost
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;
    private readonly IWebHelper _webHelper;
    private readonly NameValueCollection _inputValues;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a remote URL
    /// </summary>
    public string Url { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a method
    /// </summary>
    public string Method { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a form name
    /// </summary>
    public string FormName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a form character-sets the server can handle for form-data.
    /// </summary>
    public string AcceptCharset { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A value indicating whether we should create a new "input" HTML element for each value (in case if there are more than one) for the same "name" attributes.
    /// </summary>
    public bool NewInputForEachValue { get; set; }

    public NameValueCollection Params
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputValues;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the RemotePost class
    /// </summary>
    public RemotePost()
        : this(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<HttpContextBase>(), EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWebHelper>())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the RemotePost class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">HTTP Context</param>
    /// <param name="webHelper">Web helper</param>
    public RemotePost(HttpContextBase httpContext, IWebHelper webHelper)
    {
        this._inputValues = new NameValueCollection();
        this.Url = "http://www.someurl.com";
        this.Method = "post";
        this.FormName = "formName";

        this._httpContext = httpContext;
        this._webHelper = webHelper;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified key and value to the dictionary (to be posted).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The key of the element to add</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add.</param>
    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        _inputValues.Add(name, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post
    /// </summary>
    public void Post()
    {
        _httpContext.Response.Clear();
        _httpContext.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        _httpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptCharset))
        {
            //AcceptCharset specified
            _httpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" accept-charset=\"{3}\">", FormName, Method, Url, AcceptCharset));
        }
        else
        {
            //no AcceptCharset specified
            _httpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, Method, Url));
        }
        if (NewInputForEachValue)
        {
            foreach (string key in _inputValues.Keys)
            {
                string[] values = _inputValues.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null)
                {
                    foreach (string value in values)
                    {
                        _httpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(key), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _inputValues.Keys.Count; i++)
                _httpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_inputValues.Keys[i]), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_inputValues[_inputValues.Keys[i]])));
        }
        _httpContext.Response.Write("</form>");
        _httpContext.Response.Write("</body></html>");
        _httpContext.Response.End();
        //store a value indicating whether POST has been done
        _webHelper.IsPostBeingDone = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I came across the following post:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 - Replacing HttpContext Response Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798913/asp-net-mvc-3-replacing-httpcontext-response-not-working)

It turns out Response.Close() doesn't work quite as expected and can sometimes lose data, so the recommendation is to use the following line of code instead:

**HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();**

I tried this and instantly the RemotePost started working again. Another useful article to read about why Response.Close() doesn't always work as expected is below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx